# Prevent excel from considering date based on system's date format

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am trying to show data in excel by requesting to server. I am sending data in table format. It has some date values. I am sending the dates as `'MMM/DD/YYYY'`, which is working properly in mac.

When the same I am trying to check in windows, it is considering it as `'DD/MM/YYYY'`.

Is there any way to force excel to consider the date as `'mm/dd/yyyy'` always, `irrespective of system's date format`?

EDIT

I am adding connection in the excel (`From web` in windows), which will send request to get the data that we want to show in the excel. `There is no manual typing.`

Comment: Short answer to your question is "no". However you may have some workaround, but we need to know more details for that.

Comment: The `irrespective of system date format` hint of my old question. And yes, it's not possible, or at least need a VBA workaround. This question is as old as Excel itself, maybe.

Comment: @MátéJuhász Ok. So I am getting date as 'MM/DD/YYYY' from server. I am importing from web by adding connection in the excel, which will send request to get the data.

Comment: Could you do a query to make the server send in DD/MM/YYYY format?

Comment: Do you refresh the same connection, or establish new connection each time? Have you tried to send a correctly configured Excel file from your mac to pc?

Comment: can you change the date format in the server to something like `dd/mmm/yyyy`? (mmm = month with letters instead of numbers), that can't be interpreted differently.

Comment: @MátéJuhász User can refresh the same connection to get latest data. 
`Have you tried to send a correctly configured Excel file from your mac to pc?` - Can u explain little more?

Comment: @AdiNugroho can not use your solution. Excel is considering it as string and our calculations are on date type data (MM/DD/YYYY). :(

Comment: Try changing "/" to "-". Since this is closed I wonder if you are available to use chat?

Comment: @AdiNugroho `Try changing "/" to "-".` What difference this can make? Excel will show the date as per the system's date format, right?

Comment: Once Excel recognizes my string as date after I changed that. Might be worth a shot. Let's continue further discussion on http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/56977/discussion-shrabanee-with-adi-nugroho?tab=general

Comment: I don't have access for chat.

Comment: @Shrabanee To get your question reopened you should [edit] to explain clearly why the duplicate doesn't work for you.